# Permisos en GitHub

Tags: git, github, permisos

Quiero darle permisos a un colaborador para que pueda revisar y aceptar Pull Requests a ramas protegidas. Alguien sabe el camino para esto. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

En los settings del proyecto -> branches, vas a la sección `protected branches` y editas la rama protegida.

Verás quien puede pushear y aprobar pull requests a esas ramas. Por defecto son los admins del proyecto o de su organización (si está en una). Puedes añadir manualmente un colaborador a esa lista blanca.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo en esa imagen estoy dándole permisos a [zschuessler](https://github.com/zschuessler) en mi proyecto [phpPgAdmin6](https://github.com/HuasoFoundries/phpPgAdmin6)